# simplyfing modular equations

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Are there other ways of symplifing equations?

1. $\qquad$ Finding the inverse:

$ 42 y\equiv1 \bmod 5 \qquad 42 =5(8)+2  \qquad 5 = 2(2) +1 \qquad 2=1(2) \implies 1 = (17)5+42(-2) \implies x \equiv -2 \bmod 5 $

This method works because of Bezout’s identinty and Euclidean alghorithm

2. $\qquad 42 y\equiv1\bmod5 \qquad$ we know that $ 42 = 40 +2= 5(8)+2 \implies y \equiv2 \bmod5$
3. $\qquad$ Substracting the module

$ x\equiv 417 \bmod 120  \implies x \equiv 417 - 120 (3) \bmod120 \implies x \equiv 57 \bmod 120$

Are there other methods to simplify equations?

Comment: works with powers too, and division if coprime to the modulo.

Comment: @AaaLol_dude can you give me examples?

Comment: $5^7 \equiv 5^3 \equiv 1^3 \equiv 1 \pmod 4$

Comment: $6a+12 \equiv 18 \pmod {625} <=> a+2 \equiv 3 \pmod {625}$

Comment: $11 \equiv 5a \pmod {76} => 1 \equiv 35a \pmod{76}$